# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo with Mainactivity and Navigation drawer?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm having issues with my MainActivity starting and fragment navigation drawer working with google maps. The error i'm getting is actually two errors in one and looks like this:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.examples.blahblah.blahblah/com.examples.blahblah.blahblah.MainActivity2Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference`

Now I believe this is something to do with my fragment file which looks like this:

```
    package com.examples.blahblah.blahblah;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


    public class menu_1_fragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

        View rootview;

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu1_layout, container, false);

            MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

            return rootview;
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title("Sydney")
                    .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
                    .position(sydney));
        }
    }
```

But I will post my MainActivity if anybody thinks it could be that could be the reason I'm getting this error instead. But I wasn't getting this error until I started changing my Fragment file.

Edit: Updated Code Having issues with getSupportFragment

```
    import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


    public class menu_1_fragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

        View rootview;

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu1_layout, container, false);


            return rootview;
        }

        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title("Sydney")
                    .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
                    .position(sydney));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

to this

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentById(R.id.map));
```

Don't forget to do the necessary imports.

Edit: Try moving this code inside of onActivityCreated() and remove it from onCreateView()

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Comment: Hmm okay now it's telling me I can't resolve getSupportFragmentManager()? Could this possibly be an issue with my MainActivity?

Comment: Try importing android.support.v4.app.Fragment instead of android.app.Fragment

Comment: Hmm i've done that but now it's creating issues with my MainActivity with my navigation drawer telling me "error incompatible types required android.app.Fragment?"

Comment: Use the support Fragment across the entire project.